# I have 5 disk partitions from a disk imaged separatly, but did not image the partition table. How can I reassemble them into a coherent disk image?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, disk-image

Like the title says, I have 5 disk images, `dev-sdc1.img`, `dev-sdc2.img`, `dev-sdc3.img`, `dev-sdc4.img`, `dev-sdc5.img`. I did not save the partition table, and do not know which were primary partitions, etc. It was originally from a Windows PC with a GUID partition table.

How would I stitch them back into one partition image with a working partition table that I can copy back onto a drive of the same size as the original? I am fine with the primary/logical parts not being the same as the original.

I will be using Lubuntu or Ubuntu Mate and any tools available for Linux.

Edit: As people are asking why, this was originally a Windows laptop, I decided to put another OS on there, and backed up the partitions separately. I was not sure what some of the partitions were for (can't remember if this was a factory Win 10 install or a manual one), so I backed them all up to look at the data later. I then changed my mind about the other OS as I ended up needing a Windows machine, so I am trying to reinstall the Windows. However my first attempt to copy all the partitions onto the disk manually by making a partition table in `gparted` and `dd`-ing the images onto them did not boot.

The outputs of commands asked about:

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ file -kr dev-sdc1.img 
dev-sdc1.img: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 1021951, $MFT start cluster 42581, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 02260c83d60c81a05; contains bootstrap BOOTMGR
- DOS/MBR boot sector
-  DOS/MBR boot sector DOS executable (COM), boot code
- data
```

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ file -kr dev-sdc2.img 
dev-sdc2.img: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", sectors/cluster 2, reserved sectors 6670, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 1024000, sectors 202752 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 761, serial number 0x1ac90d22, unlabeled
- DOS/MBR boot sector
-  DOS/MBR boot sector DOS executable (COM), boot code
- data
```

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ file -kr dev-sdc3.img 
dev-sdc3.img: data
```

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ file -kr dev-sdc4.img 
dev-sdc4.img: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 1259520, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 466447340, $MFT start cluster 786432, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 07afc98edfc98a543; contains bootstrap BOOTMGR
- DOS/MBR boot sector
-  DOS/MBR boot sector DOS executable (COM), boot code
- data
```

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ file -kr dev-sdc5.img 
dev-sdc5.img: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 467707904, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 1150975, $MFT start cluster 47957, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 0e82a64152a63ded6; contains bootstrap BOOTMGR
- DOS/MBR boot sector
-  DOS/MBR boot sector DOS executable (COM), boot code
- data
```

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ wc -c dev-sdc1.img 
523239424 dev-sdc1.img
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ wc -c dev-sdc2.img 
103809024 dev-sdc2.img
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ wc -c dev-sdc3.img 
16777216 dev-sdc3.img
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ wc -c dev-sdc4.img 
238821038592 dev-sdc4.img
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ wc -c dev-sdc5.img 
589299712 dev-sdc5.img
```

Additional output for Kamil Maciorowski, I have removed some filenames with private data from the output of 4 but not others:

```
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$ sudo sh -c 'for i in 1 2 4 5; do echo "$i"; mount -o ro "dev-sdc$i.img" /mnt && { ls /mnt; umount /mnt; } done'
1
 Recovery  'System Volume Information'
2
 EFI  'System Volume Information'
4
'$Recycle.Bin'                  Cygwin-files             'Programs Self-contained'
'$WinREAgent'                   Dashcam-2023              logfile.log                      Recovery
'2023-08-12 Phone backup'          'Documents and Settings'       pics-misc                    room-pics
 2023-08-vids-room              DumpStack.log             pagefile.sys                     shared
 Backup-2022-06-12              DumpStack.log.tmp         PerfLogs                     swapfile.sys
'BBC Spaghetti-Harvest in Ticino.mp4'   From-3DS-card-backup-2023-03-25   posting                     'System Volume Information'
 bootmgr                    gp-doc                ProgramData                      Users
 BOOTNXT                    hiberfil.sys             'Program Files'                   Windows
 cygwin64                   Intel                'Program Files (x86)'                 youtube.txt
5
 Recovery  'System Volume Information'
cat@borg:~/drive-images-laptop$
```

Comment: (1) There is no concept of primary/logical in the GUID partition table, so this is not a problem. (2) Please [edit] the question and post the output of `file -kr dev-sdc1.img`, `file -kr dev-sdc2.img` and so on. (3) Please post the output of `wc -c dev-sdc?.img`.

Comment: (4) "… with a working partition table that I can copy back onto a drive" – What is the logical sector size of the drive? A partition table created for 512-byte logical sectors will not work with 4096-byte logical sectors (and vice versa).

Comment: And status of original drive is? What are you trying to accomplish? Whatever it is, it seems an extremely clumsy way.

Comment: Your attempt with `gparted` and `dd` did not boot maybe because the types of partitions were wrong. To cut off the guesswork, please do the following: `sudo sh -c 'for i in 1 2 4 5; do echo "$i"; mount -o ro "dev-sdc$i.img" /mnt && { ls /mnt; umount /mnt; } done'` and post the output. This assumes that `/mnt` is currently not used for anything important (use another mountpoint if needed); and that your Linux is able to mount FAT and NTFS (e.g. thanks to `ntfs-3g`). The code tries to temporarily mount the filesystems read-only and to show us what's inside.

Comment: (5) "stitch them back into one […] image with a working partition table that I can copy back onto a drive" – This requires space in a filesystem, generates unnecessary I/O and has to be adjusted to the size of the target drive and its logical sector size anyway. Your try with `gparted` and `dd` operated directly on the target drive, right? Do you really want a stitched image? Or can we operate on the drive (like you have tried)? (6) During your try, did you care about types of partitions? If not, maybe all the data is in the right place and we should only fix these details. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) What is the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX`? (where `sdX` is the target drive). How exactly did you `dd` the images? Maybe you did right up to some point and we don't need to start from scratch. E.g. if `sudo sh -c 'for i in 1 2 4 5; do echo "$i"; mount -o ro "/dev/sdX$i" /mnt && { ls /mnt; umount /mnt; } done'` shows you (w/o errors) the same files you got from the images then there is no point in `dd`-ing again. Still, if you're afraid your later actions mangled the data on the drive or if for any reason you want to start from scratch then please say so; nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score -1):

Manually create (using `fdisk` or similar tool) a new partition table on the target disk with partitions of the same sizes as your partition images, then `dd` your partition images onto the appropriate partitions.

Comment: This is superficial. In general partition types matter. What about them?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the partition types. I just assumed (maybe wrong) that the OP knows what is on which partition and can assign the correct types.